# Fibers of higher pullback

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Consider a morphism of schemes $f:X\rightarrow Y$, and a coherent sheaf $F$ on $Y$.
The fiber of the pullback $f^{\ast} F$ at a point $x$ is given by $F(f(x))$.
Is there a similiar formula for the fibers $(L_{n} f^{\ast} F)(x)$ of the higher derived pullbacks? I want to know when for a given $F$ and $f$ the derived pullbacks vanish (of course they always vanish when $f$ is flat).

Comment: You should take another look at your post. Some of the formatting with parentheses has gone haywire and needs editing.

Comment: Hm.. How do you want to define the derived pullbacks?

Comment: @TabesBridges I think the notation is fine. I write $F(x)$ for the fiber of a sheaf $F$ at $x$. The derived pullbacks are the derived functors of the the right exact functor $f^{\ast}$.

Comment: The notation is fine; I wasn't questioning that. It was the typesetting, which either you or someone else has fixed.